# Server daemon's sockets stop working

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, send, recv

I have an application that binds two ports: 6961 and 6963. It is an application of the form client-server-client where one client controls the other.

The application is working great, but after a seemingly random amount of accepted and closed connections, the server refuses to receive or send data thru the sockets. I can make the connection with `telnet`, but when I type something, I don't get back a response.

I have had times the server accepted up to 370 connections until it refused working, but last time it only accepted 70 connections.

I don't think it has to do with the closing of the sockets, which I think I do properly. This is my `netstat` and `lsof` output when I start the application. But I haven't really got a clue how to interpret them. I just found these when googling.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/icontrold restart
Stopping daemon
Starting daemon
$ sudo netstat | grep -E 696[13]
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.1:6963 ::ffff:192.168.1.:50005 TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.1:6963 ::ffff:192.168.1.:50759 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.1:6963 ::ffff:192.168.1.:50758 TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.1:6963 ::ffff:192.168.1.:50764 FIN_WAIT2  
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.1:6963 ::ffff:192.168.1.:50761 TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.1:6963 ::ffff:192.168.1.:50763 TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.1:6963 ::ffff:192.168.1.:50762 TIME_WAIT  
$ sudo lsof | grep icontrol
icontrold 5765       root  cwd       DIR        8,1    4096     884738 /home/ief2
icontrold 5765       root  rtd       DIR        8,1    4096          2 /
icontrold 5765       root  txt       REG        8,1  212372    5431298 /usr/sbin/icontrold
icontrold 5765       root  mem       REG        0,0                  0 [heap] (stat: No such file or directory)
icontrold 5765       root  mem       REG        8,1   77808    5425003 /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
icontrold 5765       root  mem       REG        8,1    9640     671771 /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libdl-2.4.so
icontrold 5765       root  mem       REG        8,1 1248904     671768 /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.4.so
icontrold 5765       root  mem       REG        8,1   40208     671760 /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
icontrold 5765       root  mem       REG        8,1  149284     671772 /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm-2.4.so
icontrold 5765       root  mem       REG        8,1  888612    5425516 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
icontrold 5765       root  mem       REG        8,1   95056     671782 /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread-2.4.so
icontrold 5765       root  mem       REG        8,1 1268568    5458256 /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
icontrold 5765       root  mem       REG        8,1  255648    5458257 /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libssl.so.0.9.8
icontrold 5765       root  mem       REG        8,1  105112     673124 /lib/ld-2.4.so
icontrold 5765       root    0u     IPv6      16962                TCP *:6963 (LISTEN)
icontrold 5765       root    1u     IPv6      16965                TCP *:6961 (LISTEN)
icontrold 5765       root    4u     IPv6      16968                TCP 192.168.1.10:6963->192.168.1.4:50759 (ESTABLISHED)
$
```

This is the output of both commands when the server stops accepting:

```
$ sudo lsof | grep icontrol
icontrold 4645       root  cwd       DIR        8,1    4096    7913473 /root
icontrold 4645       root  rtd       DIR        8,1    4096          2 /
icontrold 4645       root  txt       REG        8,1  212372    5431298 /usr/sbin/icontrold
icontrold 4645       root  mem       REG        0,0                  0 [heap] (stat: No such file or directory)
icontrold 4645       root  mem       REG        8,1   77808    5425003 /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
icontrold 4645       root  mem       REG        8,1    9640     671771 /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libdl-2.4.so
icontrold 4645       root  mem       REG        8,1 1248904     671768 /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.4.so
icontrold 4645       root  mem       REG        8,1   40208     671760 /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
icontrold 4645       root  mem       REG        8,1  149284     671772 /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libm-2.4.so
icontrold 4645       root  mem       REG        8,1  888612    5425516 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
icontrold 4645       root  mem       REG        8,1   95056     671782 /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libpthread-2.4.so
icontrold 4645       root  mem       REG        8,1 1268568    5458256 /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
icontrold 4645       root  mem       REG        8,1  255648    5458257 /usr/lib/i686/cmov/libssl.so.0.9.8
icontrold 4645       root  mem       REG        8,1  105112     673124 /lib/ld-2.4.so
icontrold 4645       root    0u     IPv6      13679                TCP *:6963 (LISTEN)
icontrold 4645       root    2u     IPv6      13683                TCP *:6961 (LISTEN)
icontrold 4645       root    3u     IPv6      15276                TCP 192.168.1.10:6963->192.168.1.4:50730 (ESTABLISHED)
icontrold 4645       root    4u     IPv6      13685                TCP 192.168.1.10:6963->192.168.1.4:50005 (ESTABLISHED)
$ sudo netstat | grep 6963
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.1:6963 ::ffff:192.168.1.:50005 ESTABLISHED
tcp6       9      0 ::ffff:192.168.1.1:6963 ::ffff:192.168.1.:50730 ESTABLISHED
```

I haven't got an idea where to start looking for the bug.

Comment: Impossible to answer with just lsof and netstat output, you likely have a bug. Boil it down to a reproducer and post some code. If you truly have **no idea** where to start, run under [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) and fix anything it complains about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code clearly has a bug, and you haven't given enough information. So, start breaking down your code and figuring out what is broken. Check what you are passing to your blocking function (select/poll/kqueue/whatever) and make sure it makes sense. If it doesn't, figure out why.

I expect that you will find that you stop waiting for a handle where you should be waiting, but of course you could have a more interesting bug.